# How do I build in an exception to `::before`?

Tags: css

I'm using `::before` to add a dash between links.

```
.users ul li a::before { 
    content: " - ";
}
```

which works as expected.

However, I don't want the dash to appear before the very first option, so I added:

```
.users ul li a:first-of-type::before {
    content: "";
}
```

...but this removes *all* of the dashes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude [:first-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) using css [:not](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation)

```css
.users ul li:not(:first-child) a:before {
  content: " - ";
}
```

```html
<div class="users">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin Glad that I helped you. Please don't forget to mark is as correct when you can to help future searches :)

Comment: Done - just had to wait for the 10 min window to elapse.

Answer (score 0):

```
.users ul li a:nth-of-type(n+2)::before {
   content: " - ";
}
```

This will do the trick.